# What is the difference between one-way TCP and UDP?

Tags: wcf, tcp, udp

In WCF, you can create a one-way TCP Connection. How is this different from UDP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding WCF, `[OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]` means that the method will not block until a response/acknowledgement appears from the callee. The underlying protocol is nonetheless TCP with all the nice features like retry, error checking etc.

See also the [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.isoneway%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)